# Cordova is not defined(Barcode Scanner)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am currently using Cordova/Phonegap barcode scanner, however, I am facing an error:

```
Scanner.js:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
    at onDeviceReady (Scanner.js:12)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM608 qrScanner:1)
    at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2953)
    at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2942)
    at HTMLDocument.tapMouseUp (ionic.bundle.js:3018)
```

I am not sure what they mean by cordova is not defined. I checked my linking of js, I have ensured that my cordova.js is before my app.js and my app.js is before my Scanner.js

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/pouchdb-6.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/qr.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.qrcode.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/login.js"></script>
<script src="js/Scanner.js"></script>
<script src="js/generateQR.js"></script>
<script src="js/transactions.js"></script>
```

This is my js code syntax:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady () {
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (result) {
    })
}
```

May I know why is the error occurring?

Comment: What platform/device are you testing on?

Comment: @Aus are you sure that your device ready event is getting fired in first place??

Comment: `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` is declared two times

Comment: @Aus Did it worked finally?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` more than once